# numpy - How to compare custom dtypes conveniently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dtype that has more than 30 fields. I want to compare two objects with that dtype so that I know exactly which fields are unequal. A trivial solution would be to hard-code each field comparison in a series of if statements:

```
if (obj1['field1']==obj2['field1']) DO_SOMETHING
if (obj1['field2']==obj2['field2']) DO_SOMETHING
# ...
```

Is there a better way to compare two objects with custom dtypes and know exactly which fields match or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an object's dtype fields by [`OBJECT.dtype.names`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.names.html). So:

```
# obj1 and obj2 are elements in a numpy array with a custom dtype
for field in obj1.dtype.names:
    if obj1[field]==obj2[field]:
        # DO_SOMETHING
```